# How to publish a Ionic 5 website on GitHub pages?

Tags: github, ionic-framework, github-pages, ionic5

I already had published some website on GitHub pages with no issue. My common workflow is to build a website, upload in the root (`/`) or docs (`/docs`) directory of my repository and set up GitHub Pages in the settings.

This is my first time using Ionic. I wrote a website and I build it by running `ionic build --prod`.
Than I uploaded my contents to the `/docs` directory of the repo.
When I visit the website `https://<nickname>.github.io/<myrepo>/` it leaves me in a blank page. Inspecting with Google Chrome dev tools, I can see that scripts are referred to `https://<nickname>.github.io/script.js` instead of `https://<nickname>.github.io/<myrepo>/script.js`

*How can I make it work? What I am doing wrong?*

You can find the full source code of my project [here](https://github.com/marco97pa/MostSubYTMusicChannels/tree/master/webapp). You can build it by yourself and try if there is something wrong. The site is functional when I execute it on my local web server for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to make any React website work with GitHub Pages

### Prerequisites

- npm installed
- directory containing the React project
- git repository set on this directory and linked to the remote on GitHub

### Steps to follow

- Run `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`
- Edit the **package.json** file:

  - Add this line: `"homepage": "http://githubname.github.io/repository"`. Use your nickname and repository name
  - Add these lines in the **scripts** section:
  - ```
    "scripts": {
        //...
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
    }
    ```
- Push a commit
- ```
  git add .
  git commit -m "Create a React app and publish it to GitHub Pages"
  git push origin master
  ```
- Your website is available at http://githubname.github.io/repository

For more info see [this page](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages)

#### Additional steps for Ionic 5

If you are using Ionic 5, some errors can still occur.
In this case, visit the website on http://githubname.github.io/repository and open the Chrome Inspector Tools (*CTRL + SHIFT + I*).
Look at the **Console**: some JS or TS script could be not loaded. You can see that the browser is looking at the scripts in a wrong path.

By manually editing the index.html you can point the script to the right URLs.
Upload the edited index.html in the gh-pages branch of your GitHub repo and you are good to go.

Comment: Does this work for Ionic Angular apps as well?